# Cordova FileTransfer Plugin error code 1 for image upload

Tags: apache, cordova, file-upload, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am trying to take a picture on my phonegap app and then use the FileTransfer plugin to upload it to my server. I am getting error code 1 but there is no other explanation - this is VERY frustrating. I have scoured every piece of documentation and blog known to man with no luck.

I am using a basic LAMP server and it continues to give me an http 500 code. I am 99.9% sure this error is specific to my server because I have tested this with a different web server of mine and the code works fine. Here is the response:

```
{"code":1,"source":"file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.cordova.xxappxx/cache/1477607161788.jpg","target":"https://server.com/php/uploadPhoto.php","http_status":500,"body":"\t","exception":"https://server.com/php/uploadPhoto.php"}
```

Below is my front-end js code:

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    alert(options.fileName);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

    var params = {};
    params.value1 = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
    options.params = params;
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.headers = {Connection: "close"};

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "https://servername.com/php/uploadPhoto.php", function(result){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    }, function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }, options, true);
}
```

And here is my back-end PHP code that is being called (uploadPhoto.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
$new_image_name = "$userId.jpg";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/img/".$new_image_name);
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your server configuration?  do a simple trick if you are uploading large file using move_uploaded_file() function in PHP.
1) Create a .htaccess file in the root folder of web server.
2) Put the following code in side the .htaccess file and save it.
`php_value upload_max_filesize 8M
php_value post_max_size 8M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200`
Or change this in your php.ini file and set the configuration

Comment: I thought it may have to do with the size...but I just implemented this and still getting the same result. I'm not sure what else to try? I am attempting to base64encode the image and upload it using ajax...I hope that works

Comment: I think this is happening because of max upload size.try uploading with smaller size.or re-check your upload directory path& folder permission

Comment: I added those lines to a .htaccess file but no change...it can't be the size, my php.ini has the limit set to 2M but these files are like 100 KB on average. Maybe it is the file path? But I have set the permissions to 777 just to check that and I am still getting HTTP 500 code

Comment: try adding this on your php code  `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); ` and do one more thing create a simple html form for file upload. see the error report

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being an issue of image size. I was working on this project for a university and their servers have lots of security installed - one of these security configurations had a very small file upload size limit which was blocking the uploads. I discovered this by scanning some of the log files in the `/var/log/` directory.